# Help, i cant reference my vars!

Tags: java, slick

I have a sub-class(let's call it sub) and it contains all the function of an object in my game. In my main class(Let's call it main), i connect my sub to main. (Example sub

#### Code:

```
s = new sub();
```

Then I put my sub function at the update method.

#### Code:

```
s.myFunc();
```

Becuase in my sub, i have booleans, integers, float and more. The problem is that I don't want to connect my main class to use my main's int, booleans and others. If i connect it, it will have a stack overflow. This is what I put in my sub:

#### Code:

```
package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Armory {
   package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Store {
    public Integer wood;
    public Float probePositionX;
    public Float probePositionY;
    public Boolean StoreOn;
    public Boolean darkBought;
    public Integer money;
    public Integer darkEnergy;
    public Integer lifeLeft;
    public Integer powerLeft;
    public void darkStores(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, GameContainer gc2)
    {
        Input input1 = gc.getInput();

        //Player need wood to enter(200) If not there will be an error.
        if(wood>=200)
        {

            //Enter Store!
            if(input1.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_Q))
            {
                //Player must be in this cord!
                if((probePositionX>393 && probePositionX<555) && (probePositionY< 271 && probePositionY>171))
                {
                //The Store is On
                StoreOn=true;
                }
            }


        }



    }

}
```

In my main (update function) I put:

#### Code:

```
s.darkBought = darkBought;
s.darkEnergy = darkEnergy;
s.lifeLeft = lifeLeft;
s.money = money;
s.powerLeft = powerLeft;
s.probePositionX = probePositionX;
s.probePositionY = probePositionY;
s.StoreOn = StoreOn;
s.wood = wood;
s.darkStores(gc, sbg, gc);
```

The problem is when I go to the place, and I press q, nothing shows up. It should show another image. Is there anything wrong???

Comment: I'm not sure your listening. This is too localized question for this site. This is purely purely about java programming and not about game development. You should read about Java basics. But you don't really care do you? :-)

Comment: I edited your code to indent it properly. What's with the `Armory` thing? Bad copy/paste? Also it looks like you left the first line half finished.

Comment: Aside: Your post is pretty vague. "Is there anything wrong?" Yes, clearly - it isn't showing up though you've attempted to program it as such. There could be any number of things wrong, we just can't tell you so from this code. Maybe the input doesn't work, or the coordinates don't work, or the drawing doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

This is off topic for the site so I hope it gets moved to Stack Overflow.

Your question isn't well written and I don't really understand it, but this does stand out to me: After pressing Q, you set StoreOn to true.

In your "update function" however, you say this:

```
s.StoreOn = StoreOn;
```

Where `s.StoreOn` is a completely different variable to `StoreOn`. I'm not even sure why you're setting it, but if `StoreOn` is false, you're constantly setting `s.StoreOn` to false, either in the very frame following you pressing Q, or before that frame is even over.

---

I'm not sure what you're doing and I'm not sure you're sure either. The language in your title ("Help, I can't reference my vars!") being completely weird and not making much sense in the context says a lot. After all, you can get at your variables just fine apparently, it's just that you've got weird behaviour, so I'm not sure what you mean and you're probably not sure either.

It seems you're out of your depth and you don't really understand what you're doing very well, so the best advice I can give you is go back and complete some basic tutorials on Java programming. It looks like you're struggling, and you're missing a lot of basics. You could really, really do with learning those basics, so go back to basics and learn them.

Do a tutorial.